What does strain hysteresis look like in hard piezoelectric materials?
Many ferroelectric piezoelectric materials show a butterfly-shaped strain-field curve when they are cycled through (high) positive and negative electrical fields, see e.g. here (I copied the illustration below for clarity, source: https://www.mmech.com/matl-characteristics).

However, apparently this behaviour is only seen in soft piezoelectric materials, as most hard piezoelectric materials can only be poled or depoled at elevated temperatures. So now I was wondering: what does this electrical field-strain curve look like for hard piezoelectric materials? Would loop AB simply be repeated in the negative field, negative strain quadrant, like sketched below? And can I find examples of such curves anywhere?

